# How to bind native event with document in razor page(Blazor server side application not interop file)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How to bind native event with document in razor page(Blazor server side application not interop file)

`<button @onmousemove="@OnMouseMove">Login</Button>`

This is native event bind in **button element**.

Need bind same native event in **Document**

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you trying execute C# or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through JavaScript and JavaScript interoperability ([JS interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1)).
You need subscribe on event on front-end and call .Net code

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
 DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('SoWebApplication (Assembly Name)', 'ReturnDataAsync (Method Name)')
  .then(data => {
        //This line appears in browser dev console.
        console.log(data + " from JS.");
  });
});
```

and create static method for calling. From documentation:

> The asynchronous version is preferred to support Blazor Server scenarios. The .NET method must be public, static, and have the [JSInvokable] attribute. Calling open generic methods isn't currently supported.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

static public class Test
{
    [JSInvokable]
    public static Task<string> ReturnDataAsync()
    {
        //This line appears in server console.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from server");
        return Task.FromResult("Hello");
    }
}
```